# div background image not displaying properly in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, html, background-image

I'm helping a designer friend with a problematic page and it's throwing me for a bit of a loop as well. There should be 4 divs throughout the page with a background image and text. The page displays as expected in IE and FF but in chrome only the div that's visible on load displays it's background image. Additionally, the others will display if you highlight the space they should occupy.

I created a scrubbed version of the page as an example: http://furrylogic.net/playground/rose/example.html

Any feedback or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: It seems that it is just taking too much time to load. If you inspect the element it shows up

Answer (score 1):

I think this is going to be down to poor markup.

Example with your `<div id="hope">`:

**Currently**

```
<div id="hope">
    <div class="hinside">
        <center>
           <p></p>
           <h1 style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-transform: uppercase; opacity: 1;" data-    sb="fadeInDown" class="sb-effect-displayed animated fadeInDown">You are Loved!</h1>
           <p>&nbsp;</p>
           <p></p>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Could be simplified to:

**HTML**

```
<div id="hope" class="banner-image">
    <h1 data-sb="fadeInDown" class="sb-effect-displayed animated fadeInDown">You are Loved!</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.banner-image {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.banner-image h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 80px 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
}
```

This is just to get you on the right track, note I have removed the empty `<p>` tags and padding from the `<h1>`. I can give a working example if you provide a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: The other answer did solve the issue at hand, but I'll also pass on your suggestion for further improvement. Thank You!

Comment: If we can achieve the same output with fewer and cleaner lines of code, we should always go for that. Using too many divs and unwanted styles just don't make sense. Even Debugging gets harder that way. Jamie Read has shown us the cleaner approach which I recommend highly too :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove background-attachment: fixed from all those ids i.e #time, #bible, #hand and #hope. If that doesn't work, just let me know. :)

Comment: Are you sure it's what designer wanted? looking at main page he wanted them to be fixed(so they are staying in one place when scrolling). The question is how to solve it in this case and I think answer number one will be good start. center is one of the oddest tags in html and causes a lot of problems.

Comment: It actually does still work as intended in IE. That being said, I'm working on updating his original structure as suggested to see if we can get more consistent results. Again, thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Change the `<h1></h1>` tags to `<h1><font id="h1"></font></h1>` tags with the style or css on `#h1`. For some weird reason some browsers don't display p and h1 tags properly which the font tag sometimes eliminates. Also I would suggest using font instead of p to eliminate those line breaks some browsers put in.